# Saving/Loading keyboard shortcuts using shortcutrecorder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4, keyboard-shortcuts, nsuserdefaults

I am working on a Cocoa/Objective-C app in XCode4 that uses [shortcutrecorder](http://code.google.com/p/shortcutrecorder/) to record keyboard shortcuts and save them to defaults.

I am saving the `KeyCombo.code` and `KeyCombo.flags` attributes from the recorder, i.e:

```
[shortcutRecorder KeyCombo].code
[shortcutRecorder KeyCombo].flags
```

Where `shortcutRecorder` is an `IBOutlet` to the `SRRecorderControl`.

In order to restore saved keyboard shortcuts when the user opens the preferences window again, I load the `KeyCombo.code` and `KeyCombo.flags` attributes from defaults, and need to restore them to the `SRRecorderControl.

I am trying to do:

```
 [shortcutRecorder setKeyCombo:[
        PTKeyCombo keyComboWithKeyCode:
        [shortcutRecorder keyCombo].code
        modifiers:[shortcutRecorder cocoaToCarbonFlags:[shortcutRecorder 
        keyCombo].flags]]];
```

But this causes an error: `Sending 'id' to parameter of incompatible type 'KeyCombo' (aka 'struct_KeyCombo')`

I thought this might be because `setKeyCombo` takes a `KeyCombo` object and not a `PTKeyCombo` object, so I changed it:

```
[shortcutRecorder setKeyCombo:[
        KeyCombo keyComboWithKeyCode:
        [shortcutRecorder keyCombo].code
        modifiers:[shortcutRecorder cocoaToCarbonFlags:[shortcutRecorder 
                keyCombo].flags]]];
```

But now I receive the error: `Receiver type 'KeyCombo' (aka 'struct_KeyCombo') is not an Objective-C class`

I'm not sure how to go about creating a valid object to pass to `setKeyCombo`. Any tips on the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SRMakeKeyCombo(code, flags)`